# LXC/docker.io & kernel updates

Tags: linux-kernel, docker, lxc

Linux Containers use the Kernel of their host system. How do I make sure that the containers are OK after a major upgrade of the kernel of the host system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A paranoid solution would be to:

- copy the containers to a test host running the new kernel,
- start the containers in isolation (e.g. routing disabled, or `iptables` rule to block outgoing traffic),
- check that everything is OK,
- if it works, roll out the kernel upgrade on the production hosts.

This is quite easy with Docker, since you can `docker push` your containers from the production setup and `docker pull` them from the test setup.

But generally speaking, as long as you're upgrading, you should be fine. If you downgrade to an older kernel version (e.g. 3.8+ to <3.8) you might see some issues, but it's not related to the downgrade operation; it's just that pre-3.8 kernels have issues with namespaces (except when relevant patches have been backported).